# Haskell, modyfying only one field of structure

Tags: haskell

I have a some structure:

```
data S = { 
  a :: Integer,
  b :: Integer,
  c :: String,
  d :: Map String Integer
}
```

I closed it in my `State monad`, And I am using it in following way:

```
s <- get
let S {a = a', b =b', c=c', d=d'} s   
put $ S {a = a' + 1, b = b', c= c', d = d'}
```

As you can see, when I would like to modify/read only one field (here `a`), I must get and put all fields - it is embarassing - otherwise I get warnings and sometimes runtime errors.

Can you try to propose me some solution to make it better and cleaner ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a record update and specify only the fields you want to update. Also, you can extract a particular field during pattern matching.

```
s@S{ a = a' } <- get 
put $ s{ a = a' + 1 }
```

---

Alternately, if you find yourself doing a lot of this sort of thing, you might want to use [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). With `lens`, you would have to make lenses for `S` (which requires turning on `-XTemplateHaskell`)

```
data S = { _a, _b :: Integer, _c :: String, _d :: Map String Integer }
makeLenses ''S
```

But then, in your state monad you can just write

```
a += 1
```

Yep, this is legitimate Haskell. [`+=`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:-43--61-) is actually a thing.